# How can I create AVI movie file from a set of 3d (and 4d matrices) in Matlab on Windows 7?

Tags: matlab, matrix, rgb, movie

I have 2 matrices; one 3d matrix its size is for example (100* 400 * 90 ;  (90 is time)) and also I have a 4 dimension matrix. I want to make AVI file for both of them separately. unfortunately, each code I found via Internet couldn't run properly. Hope your knowledge can help me.
i tried with aviobj and mov2avi .... but I couldn't get answer.

### Edit

I want to make AVI file based on a 420*320*3*90 matrix

Could anyone tell me how can I make an AVI video from RGB Images?

Comment: what are the dimensions of the 4D array? how do you plan to convert 4D data into a video?

Comment: My variable is a 4D matrix; because I stored about 90 frames of RGB images. So, the fourth dimension is time or the number of RGB images.

Comment: @so you have an array of size `100`-by-`400`-by-`90`-by-`3`?

Comment: I have 2 matrices: 1- RGB matrix: 420*320*240*90 and another : 420*320*90.  90 is the number of frames. It will be fine even if I can convert 3d matrix to avi if you can do it please.

Comment: how exactly 420x320x240x90 is an RGB movie? which dimenssion is the color?

Comment: But for your question have a look to [VideoWriter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriterclass.html)

Comment: first dimension is R; second is G and third is B. fourth dimension is Time. Please do not care the numbers.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, I tried by movie2avi and could solve 3 dimension by making that matrix to a struct format. but now, I do not know how to do it for 4 dimension. I do not have a set of Images, I just have a stacked matrix.

Comment: Your matrix is odd form. I never saw matrix like that before. You need Something like 420x320x3x90, where it ImageHeight x ImageWidth x NbChannel x NbFrames (Time). I don't really understand how works your matrix. That maybe why movie2avi doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, Thank you. I made mistake. So, If I want to make AVI file based on 420*320*3*90, How can I put it into movie2avi or any other built in function as input argument? I mean how to make an RGB video file?

Comment: Dear Shai, sorry for confusing you.

Comment: Could anyone tell me how can I make an AVI video from RGB Images?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: how to make AVI video file for RGB images:

```
mov(1:num_frames) = struct('cdata', [],'colormap', []);


for i=1:90
    ..
    mov(1,i).cdata=rgb(:,:,:,i);
    ..
end
movie2avi(mov, 'RGB.avi', 'compression', 'None');
```